# Update taking time in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one query regarding update

```
update stg set flg = 'Y' where exists (
    select 1
    from   err
    where  err.pid = stg.pid
    and    err.imp_id = stg.imp_id
    and    err.error_id = 999 )
and pid = 123 ;
```

so staging table should update its records when entry is there in err table 
for 999 error_id. Err 
table has 3mn records for 999.Stg has total 13mn records for 123 pid. Both 
tables are partition 
on pid. Err has index on all 3 cols. This is running so slow.
Please suggest any better approach for doing this. I have to do this in 
plsql block.ALso let me know if more details are required. This job will run daily. No foreign keys .

Comment: Tag your question properly.  `SQL` is just a language used by multiple dbms.  So which dbms is this for???

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you we'd need to know the schema for stg and err. That would include their indexes and foreign keys. And what is the output of `explain` for that statement?

Comment: both are in same schema, for err table we have one composite index on allthe 3 cols used in query.On stg we have composite index on 4 cols including pid and imp_id.

Comment: @henna Piecemeal information makes it harder to answer the question. It will be easier to answer if we can see the relevant schema and indexes. The details of the composite indexes are important.

Comment: On stg we have composite index on 4 cols including( pid ,imp_id,status,flg) in same order.We only have 1-1 index on both the tables.No foreign keys.

Comment: EDIT the question (press the edit button) and please put all the details in the question including complete DDL for the tables, indexes and run an explain plan and show the results.  thank you.

Comment: I cant mention the DDL here , but in explain plan for err single partition is searched and also using index and update on stg table is in nested loop

Comment: How many rows are there in stg with pid = 123? How many rows get updated? How long does it take to get 1 row from err using test values for `pid`, `imp_id` and `error_id`? How is `err` partitioned?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson -13mn records in stg for 123.Arnd 3 mn rows get updated.Err is interval partitioned on pid i.e. one partition will be accessed. Its taking less than a second to fetch row from err as there is an index on all 3 cols .And combination of pid and imp_id is unique in both the tables.

Comment: 13 million times "less than a second" could be several months. Perhaps it would do better with full scans and a hash join. Are the stats up to date? Are the estimates in the execution plan correct?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson less than a second means for first 50 rows in sql developer.stats are not stale.I was trying with merge but it was also slow

Comment: 50 rows per pid/imp_id/error_id? I thought that was unique? Anyway I think we are going to have to see all the details including `dbms_xplan` output included in the question before anyone can see what the underlying problem might be. You might also run a [SQL Monitor report](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/real-time-sql-monitoring-11gr1) if you are licenced (requires Enterprise Edition and the Diagnostics and Tuning option), although the output will be too big to share here.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to transform your update into an **inline view** update, look for an example here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/updates-based-on-queries

So I tried to reproduce a test case with the information you did provide:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> create table err (pid number not null, imp_id number not null, error_id number not null);

Table created.

SQL> create table stg (pid number not null, imp_id number not null, flg char(1) not null );

Table created.

SQL> insert into stg select 123, level, 'N' from dual connect by level <= 13000000;

13000000 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into err select 123, level, 999 from dual connect by level <= 3000000;

3000000 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> set timing on
SQL> update stg set flg = 'Y' where exists (
select 1
from   err
where  err.pid = stg.pid
and    err.imp_id = stg.imp_id
and    err.error_id = 999 )
and pid = 123;

3000000 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:13.63
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:09.71
SQL> create unique index udx_err on err (pid, imp_id, error_id);

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:06.21
SQL> create index idx_stg on stg (pid, imp_id);

Index created.

Elapsed: 00:00:23.21
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( user, 'ERR' );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.11
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( user, 'STG' );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:09.44
SQL> update stg set flg = 'Y' where exists (
select 1
from   err
where  err.pid = stg.pid
and    err.imp_id = stg.imp_id
and    err.error_id = 999 )
and pid = 123;

3000000 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:13.84
SQL> explain plan for update stg set flg = 'Y' where exists (
select 1
from   err
where  err.pid = stg.pid
and    err.imp_id = stg.imp_id
and    err.error_id = 999 )
and pid = 123;

Explained.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.display(format => 'ALL'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 728722196

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT      |      |  3002K|    74M|       | 29231   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  UPDATE               | STG  |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI|      |  3002K|    74M|    74M| 29231   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | ERR  |  2999K|    40M|       |  2146   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL  | STG  |    12M|   148M|       |  8547   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------
   1 - SEL$3FF8579E
   3 - SEL$3FF8579E / ERR@SEL$1
   4 - SEL$3FF8579E / STG@UPD$1

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ERR"."PID"="STG"."PID" AND "ERR"."IMP_ID"="STG"."IMP_ID")
   3 - filter("ERR"."ERROR_ID"=999 AND "ERR"."PID"=123)
   4 - filter("PID"=123)

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   2 - (#keys=2; upd=4; cmp=1,2) "STG"."PID"[NUMBER,22], "STG"."IMP_ID"[NUMBER,22], "STG".ROWID[ROWID,10], "FLG"[CHARACTER,1]
   3 - (rowset=256) "ERR"."PID"[NUMBER,22], "ERR"."IMP_ID"[NUMBER,22], "ERR"."ERROR_ID"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - "STG".ROWID[ROWID,10], "PID"[NUMBER,22], "STG"."IMP_ID"[NUMBER,22], "FLG"[CHARACTER,1]

35 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.08
```

Using inline view now:

```
SQL> update (select stg.flg
      from stg, err
     where err.pid = stg.pid
       and err.imp_id = stg.imp_id
       and err.error_id = 999
               and stg.pid = 123
            )
     set flg = 'Y';

3000000 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:05.69
SQL>
```

And it runs faster...

My advices:
- check your statistics
- check these indexes, are they well defined?
- check your columns data types
- check if columns should be not nullable

Your execution plan should not use indexes here as it will run forever...

Comment: with inline view its giving error -SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: Do you have primary key(s) and foreign key? if so please denote the columns and dependencies please.

Comment: no foreign keys and primary key defined on tables . Howevery combination of pid and imp_id is unique in stg table. But err table can have multiple records for pid and imp_id

Comment: What happen when you make these indexes invisible?

Comment: I tried using inline view but got -SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table. IS it because combination of all 3 cols in err table is not unique. Also flg in stg can have 3 values 'N''Y' or null

Comment: also why your direct update is not using index in explain plan. Did you make them invisible.? I checked my explain plan its using index on err table

Comment: no the index are not invisible, I'm using 19.3.0 release with up to date statistics

Comment: The problem we all have here is related to the lack of information regarding your DDL... the nullability of the columns can indeed be important... adding the detailed execution plan would be very helpful here as well.

Comment: do you have separate discussion room, can you invite me there